# Calculate open hours

Tags: sql

I am using a SQL query

```
select 
    datediff(hour, Convert(DateTime, Convert(DateTime, Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)) + '' +  
             Convert(varchar, complainttime, 114)), dateadd(mi, 330, GETUTCDATE())) 
from complaintregister
```

it creates results like:

```
No column name
  15455
  15259
  15190
  15190
  15165
   300
   200
  1000
   500
```

and I want the colum only containg values > 1000

Comment: Please, for the convenience of trying to answer your question, format your SQL query nicely and use the 'Code Sample' feature of StackOverflow's editor.

Comment: Please fix your question in regards to spelling and formatting.

Comment: I strongly suspect you don't *really* need three levels of nested conversions - or if you do, you should fix the schema of your database. What exactly are you trying to compute, and what are the types of your fields?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon Skeet's comment, but to answer your question, surely you only need to add a where clause: "where [Open Hours] > 500"?