# Calculate the number of hours a ticket is open, using SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate open hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329684/calculate-open-hours)

I am using a SQL query to calculate the "open hours" for a complaint from it's `complaintdate` until now.

```
Select datediff(hour, 
  Convert(DateTime, 
    Convert(DateTime, 
      Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)
    ) + '' +
    Convert(varchar, complainttime, 114)
  ), 
  dateadd(mi, 330, GETUTCDATE())
) as [Open Hours] from complaintregister
```

and getting a column

```
Open Hours
15139
15070
15070
15070
15070
100
300
200
400
```

I want to get open hours only more than 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```
select * from ( Select datediff(hour, 
      Convert(DateTime, 
        Convert(DateTime, 
          Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)
        ) + '' +
        Convert(varchar, complainttime, 114)
      ), 
      dateadd(mi, 330, GETUTCDATE())
    ) as [Open Hours] from complaintregister ) t where t.[Open Hours]>500
```

Comment: but ists showng an error Invalid column name 'Open Hours'.

Comment: @roshan: If that solution works for you - please get in the habit of **accepting** the best answer provided, the one solving your problem. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)